# An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I have recently updated a legacy compact framework application to support Windows Mobile 6.5 but after going through my backwards compatability testing I have an issue with the WinCE 5 device.

When attempting to run the application from both the EXE and the debugger I get the "An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Unknown Module." exception but its not giving me any idea which dll / type it has issue with.

The changes do work on the Windows Mobile 6.5 Motorola device and the Pocket PC 2003 Psion Device but not on the WinCE5 Psion device.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can find out which reference is causing me the issue. I have tried removing the new references to the Symbol barcoding and imaging libraries but I am still getting the same error.

Thanks,

Phil

UPDATE:
OK, it looks like the .Net Compact Framework installation had corrupted some how. I flattened the device, reinstalled and everything appears to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it looks like the .Net Compact Framework installation had corrupted some how. I flattened the device, reinstalled and everything appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a reference to the Micrsoft.WindowsMobile assembly in the app?  If so this will cause a failure (though I'm not 100% certain what the failure would look like, as I've not tried it in a long time).  The WindowsMobile functionality is in an assembly that is already present on WinMo devices (so not part of the CF that is deployed by Studio), so a `TypeLoadException` wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: No reference to the Windows mobile assembly. The only OS specific assembly I have is the Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.

Comment: The full list of asseblies is below plus a couple of internal assemblies.

Comment: Ionic.Zip.CF
Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms
OpenNETCF
OpenNETCF.Net
OpenNETCF.Windows.Forms
PsionTeklogixNet
PtxImagerNet
Symbol
Symbol.Barcode
Symbol.Imaging
Symbol.StandardForms
System
System.Core
System.Data
System.Data.SqlClient
System.Data.SqlServerCe
System.Drawing
System.Web.Services
System.Windows.Forms
System.Xml
System.Xml.Linq

Comment: The new assemblies are the Symbold ones which I have removed, along with the associated code, and the error still occured. Nothing else should have changed